# Insert text at position 'x' in a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying modify my `<div>` on the fly. I have (start) position and text. I must insert text at this position.

```
date = {
    position: 5,
    text: 'nice'
}

<div class="something">I like cookies</div>
```

Do you have any idea how it do without substring() or substr().

Comment: "how it do without substring() or substr()" - anything particularly wrong with `substr()`?

Comment: Why isn't `substring` allowed to be used? Is this homework?

Comment: (shhh... job interview question)

Comment: I have an idea how it use with substring() or substr() and I was hoping that there is some other solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `slice()` ?

```
date = {
    position: 7,
    text: 'nice '
}

var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('something')[0],
    txt  = elem.innerHTML;
    _txt = txt.slice(0, date.position) + date.text + txt.slice(date.position, txt.length);

elem.innerHTML = _txt;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NYkRX/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
        text: 'nice',
        position: 5
    },
    element1 = document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0],
    str1 = element1.innerHTML, //assume you can use getElementsByClassName; otherwise write a function for it.
    i,
    output = '';

for (i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (i === data.position) {
        output += str1[i] + data.text;
    }
    output += str1[i]
}
element1.innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about with `slice`?

```
"foo bar".slice(0, 3) == "foo"
"foo bar".slice(3)    == " bar"
"foo bar".slice(-3)   == "bar"
"foo bar".slice(-2)   == "ar"
```

So given your example you would end up with something like this:

```
var date = {
    position: 5,
    text: 'nice'
};

var foo = $('<div class="something">I like cookies</div>').text();
var bar = foo.slice(0, date.position) + date.text + foo.slice(date.position);
```

[image]